# Drawing 2 Parallel Lines in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, line

I want to make a program that draw two lines so that they touch each other without crossing, but the image i get is different.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        launch(args);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.setTitle("Calcolo di PiGreco");
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        Line orizzontalline = new Line(0, 250, 500, 250);
        Line verticalline= new Line(50, 0, 50, 250);
        root.getChildren().add(orizzontalline);
        root.getChildren().add(verticalline);


        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

the origin point where the start of the line is calculated should be the same, but in fact it is different

Comment: Don't use `StackPane` as root. Use `Pane`. `StackPane`, by default, will center any noded added to it. If there are multiple nodes, `StackPane` with will stack them.

Comment: [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html)

Comment: I think you mean `Perpendicular` and not `Parallel`. `Parallel` lines never touch.